# How to get all data out of many to many field?

Tags: python, django

what i want to do here is to show current user "Signels" from all the users he is following. but can't get data of more then one user out.

models.py

```
class Signels(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
     coin_name = models.CharField(max_length=300 , null=True, blank=True)
     symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10 , null=True, blank=True)
     title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=True, blank=True)
     buy =  models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True, blank=True)
     sell =  models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True, blank=True)

class Follow(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='current_user', null=True)
     Following = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

views.py

```
    def post(request):
        user1 = request.user
        user_now = Follow.objects.get(user=user1)
        for followed in user_now.Following.all():
            signel = Signels.objects.filter(author=followed)
            return render(request, 'posts/all.html', { "signels" : signel } )
```

all.html

```
        {% for i in signels %}

        <div class="card post_card ">

       <a type="button" href="/profile/{{i.author.username}}" 
     class="username"><b>{{i.author.username}}</b></a>
       <p class="category">{{i.title}} </p>
      <p class="category"><b>{{i.coin_name}}({{i.symbol}})</b></p>
        <b class="buy">buy</b>:{{ i.buy }} ,  &nbsp;
         <b class="sell">sell</b>: {{i.sell}},  &nbsp;


        {% endfor %}
```

the result i am getting in "all.html" is that it,s showing all the Signals from 1st user he is following in many to many field. but nothing from other users he is following. i want current user to see all the Signels from  all the users he is following.

Comment: I think you have your return in the for loop, you might need to gather all the signels and get the return out of the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain all the `Signels` of `author`s that are followed by a given user with:

```
Signels.objects.filter(author__follow__user=request.user)
```

so in the view, we can write this like:

```
def post(request):
    signels = Signels.objects.filter(author__follow__user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'posts/all.html', { "signels" : signels } )
```

But I'm not sure that your current modeling is the right one. It might be better to link two users to a `Follow` model, and thus let `Follow` act as a "through" model between two users. Right now the `Follow` object is basically an extra "proxy" over the `User` model, which thus creates an extra table. With your modeling it can happen that a `User` has two (or more) `Follow` objects that each contain a set of `following`s. This will also result in an extra `JOIN`, making the query thus a bit "harder" to evaluate.

Probably a more effective "following" system is perhaps:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name='current_user',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='followees'
    )
    followee = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name='current_user',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='followers'
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together=('followers', 'followee')
```

In that case the query is:

```
Signels.objects.filter(author__followers__follower=request.user)
```

Here a user can not follow the same user twice, and we prevent creating an extra "hidden" table by a many-to-many relation.

or you can [create a custom user model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) where you then add a many-to-many relation for following.

Comment: it worked thank u so much. and sorry i am having trouble understanding what u r saying in last. i am just a beginner. i struggled for many hours in making this follow system. so if u explain it with some example or code .it will be help full.

Comment: @NeerajJoon: see edit for a possible improvement. It of course depends on the specific application, etc.